# Open console inside gui application

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I'm trying to create a program in C++, which open with him, within the form, the CMD, so that I can run a program within the CMD that is inside the program. As an example, in this photo:

[image]

I found some examples, but could not implement them in code, so, I ask your help... To be more precise, I want to create a function in a dll, so I can call this CMD, starting from any language

> ---
>
> basically an embedding a Console

Comment: Honestly the best I can think of is making a child window with the `ConsoleWindowClass` class. Consoles are a bit peculiar sometimes, though.

Answer (score 0):

I see two methods:

- Write your own console widget and pass all entered command to the std::system command
- Do what is described in [How to open a console window in a Win32 application](http://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2008/08/29/console-window-win32-app/)

Comment: Oh, thanks, but, using this, how i can put buttons, labels ... ?

Comment: For the second method, you have to use a separate window. The console can't be directly included in an application.
But I think the first method enables you to fake the integration of the console in your app. You just need to write the control code of a text edit (ie, filter some characters and send the inputed line to std::system whenever the user press 'enter'). It have the advantage of being 'portable' (if you use a portable GUI, like with Qt), because std::system is standard.

Comment: OK, but, I need to open a program with TUI, like this:
http://i.imgur.com/zkC5V.png

Comment: I never played with Tui libs, but if they use the standard input/output streams you can redirect it to the 'fake' console.

Or you will have to use a separate window.